# Why is Gaze consuming high CPU?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, profiling

I'm running gaze (https://github.com/shama/gaze) to watch change over several folders which contain some hundreds of files. Now the process is consuming a steady 15% CPU, which means one full core out of the four.

I did a check - I ran fs.watch over the same list of folders, and get 0.0% CPU with similar functionality.

Now, question is - how do I figure out what gaze is doing, besides reading the code? Is there any profiling tool?

In addition - do you already know what the problem is maybe?

System details:
OSX 10.10
Node 6.9.1
Gaze 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason turned out to be the usage of fs.watchFile with the default **gaze** interval of 100ms. The default interval of Node's native function is 5007ms (according to docs - https://nodejs.org/docs/v6.9.1/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) so calling gaze with interval === 5007 fixes the issue (as well as commenting out fs.watchFile in the gaze source).

My concern now is that both fs.watch and fs.watchFile are used and one is probably redundant, but that's another issue.

P.S. I tried to profile the process with node --prof but didn't find info that was useful for me.